# How to read and display from realtime database [Firebase]?

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio

I tried following various youtube videos for guides in order to display the current user information in user profile.However, I still failed on displaying those data. Those data are name, gmail and phone numbers.

My current java code on ProfileActivity

```
    FirebaseUser user;
    DatabaseReference reference;
    String userID;

    Button MainMenu,Logout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        userID = user.getUid();

        final TextView ViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Name);
        final TextView ViewEmail = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.Email);
        final TextView ViewPhonenumber = (TextView)  findViewById(R.id.Phonenumber);

        reference.child(userID).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                users userProfile = snapshot.getValue(users.class);

                if(userProfile != null){
                    String name = userProfile.Name;
                    String email = userProfile.Email;
                    String phonenumber = userProfile.Phonenumber;


                    ViewName.setText(name);
                    ViewEmail.setText(email);
                    ViewPhonenumber.setText(phonenumber);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this,"Something wrong happened",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

My current file for users.java

```
    public String Name;
    public String Email;
    public String Phonenumber;

    public users(){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public String getPhonenumber() {
        return Phonenumber;
    }

    public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber) {
        Phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }
}
```

My realtime database in Firebase
[image]

UPDATED with Register.java class so you guys might get clear view on how my code looks like

````
    EditText mFullName,mEmail,mPassword,mPhone;
    Button mRegisterButton;
    TextView mLoginButton;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference root = db.getReference().child("users");

    users users;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mFullName           = findViewById(R.id.Name);
        mEmail              = findViewById(R.id.Email);
        mPassword           = findViewById(R.id.Password);
        mPhone              = findViewById(R.id.Phonenumber);
        mRegisterButton     = findViewById(R.id.registerbutton);
        mLoginButton        = findViewById(R.id.loginpage);


        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        if(fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

        }


        mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = mEmail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = mPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String name = mFullName.getText().toString();
                String number =mPhone.getText().toString();

                HashMap<String , String> userMap = new HashMap<>();

                userMap.put("name",name);
                userMap.put("email",email);
                userMap.put("phone",number);



                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email))
                {
                    mEmail.setError("Email is required!");
                    return;
                }

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
                {
                    mPassword.setError("Password is required!");
                    return;
                }

                if(password.length() < 6)
                {
                    mPassword.setError(("Password must be longer than 6"));
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            root.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(userMap);
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"User Created",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"Error" + task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });```
````

Comment: please post your Firebase upload Code in stackoverflow

Comment: what you mean by upload code? @VijayS

Comment: how you  upload data in firebase ??

Comment: @VijayS its not called upload, Its called add and remove

Answer (score 1):

You're getting no data from the database because the names of the properties inside the `users` class are different than the ones in the database. See `Name` (capital `N`) in the class vs. `name` (lower case letter `n`) in the database?

To solve this, you should simply change the class to look like this:

```
class users
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String phonenumber;

    public users(){

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPhonenumber() {
        return phonenumber;
    }

    public void setPhonenumber(String phonenumber) {
        this.phonenumber = phonenumber;
    }
}
```

Please also note that the fields now are set private instead of public. Besides that, to refer to the class members, you have to use `this`, which is an instance of the class.

---

**P.S.** Also remember that in your database you're using pushed IDs and **not** UIDs that are coming from the authentication operation.

Comment: I changed all like you suggested but it seems that it didn't appear on user profile.

Comment: Have you also changed that pushed ID into the UID that comes from Firebase authentication? If yes, show us the new database schema.

Comment: Oh yeah,hang on. I'm trying to figure that out on how to change from pushed ID to UID.

Comment: Don't use `push()`, but use `.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())`, when adding data.

Comment: I removed the push part that was once it's like `root.push().setValue(userMap)`. Should it be like this ? `root.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(userMap);`

Comment: Most likely with an intermediate call to `root.child("users")...`. And the same reference should be used when you read the data. Does it work now?

Comment: I added Register.java in the main thread, so you can get a better look on my code.

Comment: Yes, looks good to me. Does it work now?

Comment: Sadly,it didn't work. Nothing appear on user profile page

Comment: Is the user present in the Firebase console right after the authentication? Have you also tried to attach a listener to `.setValue(userMap)` to see if something goes wrong?

Comment: User UID does present whenever new account/user is made. I also don't know how to attach a listener to `.setValue(userMap)`

Comment: Yes, when a new account is created, a new UID is generated. How to attach a listener? In the exact same way you already did `.setValue(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(...)`

Comment: I tried `root.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(userMap);` again, it worked like you suggested. It's so weird why it didn't work when trying that code for 1st time. Thanks a lot for the help. I wanna try the update part on User Profile after this. Expect to see another question from me.

Comment: Good to hear that it worked. It didn't work the first time because of those names and the UID.

Comment: Besides that, can I help you with other information?

Comment: I'm about to do the update part.Is there any other way to contact you?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Change your User class fields to  :

   public String name;
   public String email;
   public String phone;

   also rename getter and setters
2. Log error in onCancelled() if this does not work

Comment: I tried changing the class field like you told me but it didnt work. Also, what to rename on those getters and setters?

Comment: use android studio for generating getters and setters

use alt + Enter (put cursor on field ,then use these shortcut)

also check if you are getting snapshot or not using debugging